# Change screen dpi in Linux Mint 15?

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

I just installed Linux Mint 15 Cinnamon in a VM on my Retina Macbook Pro. It all works just fine, but I'm currently bound to running it at 1280x800 because otherwise all the text becomes illegibly small.

Is there some way to change screen DPI, in such a way that text and possibly also GUI elements will scale up to look ok on larger resolutions?

If this isn't possible in Cinnamon, can you recommend another DE that will play nicely with high-DPI screens? I've heard KDE works quite well, but if you know another one that isn't such a resource hog, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**System-Fonts**

You can make the fonts larger.
Go to...

```
Menu>System Tools>System Settings>Appearance>Fonts
```

..To change the system wide fonts.

Then, to change the Nemo desktop font size, I installed dconf-tools and then selected org>nemo>desktop to increase the desktop font sizes.

**GTK-Apps**
To make fonts larger from GTK-Apps like GIMP, you have to make additional changes:

> 1. Open home folder, press Ctrl+H (or click View > Show hidden files)
> 2. File > click "Create new document" > Empty document
> 3. Create a file named .gtkrc-2.0 (note the dot at beginning)
> 4. Open file and enter this line, of course substituting your own username for "your-user-name" :) :
>
>    `include '/home/your-user-name/.gtkrc.mine'`
> 5. Save the file
> 6. Close
> 7. Create another file named `.gtkrc-1.2-gnome2`
> 8. Open file and enter the same line:
>
>    `include '/home/your-user-name/.gtkrc.mine'`
> 9. Save the file
> 10. Close
> 11. Create this file named `.gtkrc.mine`
> 12. Open the file
> 13. Enter the following text (just replace "11" with the value of the size of text you want):
>
>     `style "gedit"`
>         `{`
>         `font_name = "11"`
>         `}`
>       `widget_class "*" style "gedit"`
>         `gtk-font-name = "11"`
> 14. Save file
> 15. Close

[Source](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=208&t=136846#)